# Activity Diagram with timed events

Tags: uml, activity-diagram, timed-events

Draw an activity diagram
using signals to capture the following series of events:

1. Three days before the flight, my travel agent emails me with a list
   of required travel documents.
2. If the list is not received by the three day deadline I cancel the flight.
3. Otherwise: Three hours before the flight, I order a taxi. When the taxi arrives, I depart for the airport

Hi I'm wondering can any one help me with this I have an exam coming up and am having trouble, especially with timed events.
Thank you.

Comment: OK... so what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

The timing is planned in Timing diagrams, maybe a bit in State machine or Sequence diagrams, but Activity diagram is inconvenient for it. And definitely your examples are not so non-standard.

Use Timing diagram!

Look for an example [here](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/highlight/highlightuml2support.jsp),  search for "timing" on the page